# How to replace MySQL insert parametrized query in JForm with HQL?

Tags: mysql, hql, jform

I have to create insert parametrized query in HQL in JForm.

I already created it in MySQL, but I have problem with HQL...

```
private void jBtn_submitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

     String query = "insert into schema.table values(?,?,?,?,?)";
      try
      {   
        pst = kon.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setString(1, null);
        pst.setString(2, jTxtF_name.getText());
        pst.setString(3, jTxtF_year.getText());
        pst.setString(4, jTxtF_adres.getText());
        pst.setString(5, jTxtF_income.getText());

        pst.execute();
        pst.close();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "successfully import");        
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
      }    
        jTxtF_name.setText("");        
        jTxtF_year.setText("");
        jTxtF_adres.setText("");
        jTxtF_income.setText("");

    }
```

Comment: `entityManager.persist(myEntity)`

Comment: Could you explain little bit more... I am beginner in programming...

Comment: The way to insert something in a table with JPA is to create an instance of the entity mapped to that table and to persist this entity using the EntityManager. JPA needs to be learnt. Read a good book, and/or tutorials, and/or the Hibernate documentation. This is fundamental stuff. You don't use an ORM like Hibernate like you use JDBC.

Comment: I have to use hibernate, that is my assignment... not JPA, hibernate...

Comment: It's the same thing. You would use session.persist() then.